# ¿Cómo desactivo el menú hamburguesa de Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, web

Quiero desactivar o optimizar el menú hamburguesa que aparece en un navbar al entrar desde un dispositivo móvil.

Estoy utilizando Bootstrap 5

Este es el código del navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: #8dbb30;">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="files/DF-logonormalblanco2png.png" width="40%"></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div style="margin-left: -300px; font-size: 18px;" class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav"><!--  -->
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Inicio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="sobrenosotros">Sobre nosotros</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

**Así es como se ve desde una computadora**
[image]

**Así es como se ve desde un télefono móvil**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ya, muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Desactivar u optimizar? ¿Qué es lo que necesitas y qué has intentado? Por favor revisa [ask]

Answer (score 0):

talves te refieras a solo quitar el boton sin que desaparescan los items, puedes hacerlo  así (en caso de querer quitarlo):

```
`    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light sticky-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Algo OP</a>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Inicio</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sobre Nosotros</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
    </nav>`
```

pero si quieres que el botón hamburguesa este a un lado hazlo así:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light sticky-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Algo OP</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Inicio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sobre Nosotros</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

te recomendaría leer mas a profundidad la documentación de Bootstrap 5

Comment: Gracias! Lo voy a probar...